# MYSQL - Cannot use join and count in where

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use this query

```
SELECT `d`.*,COUNT(*) as `used`,`o`.`id` 
FROM rs_discount_code as `d` 
LEFT JOIN rs_order as `o` ON `d`.`code` = `o`.`voucher_code` 
WHERE `d`.`active` = 'yes' 
  AND `d`.`date_to` >= '2015-11-03 15:27:57' 
  AND (`o`.`id` IS NULL) 
   OR (`o`.`id` IS NOT NULL AND `used` < `d`.`use_count`) 
GROUP BY `d`.`id`
```

MYSQL result is

```
Unknown column 'used' in 'where clause'
```

any suggestion how to solve it?

Comment: Use a `having` clause.  That is what you use for filtering by aggregated values in an aggregation query.  One does imagine that you want a `group by` in there somewhere.

Comment: your query is incomplete! check the end of query string in OP

Comment: try `COUNT(o.voucher_code)` instead of `COUNT(*)`   and here `AND \`used\` < \`d\`.\`use_count\`)` alias missed try probably `AND o.used < d.use_count)`